# Keep my view as clean as possible (for clarity)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view (asp.net mvc razor) I would like to display a **description** (from my model) in french or dutch based on current thread culture. Below is my actual implementation.

```
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@item.SubTitle</td>

            @if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "fr-BE") { 
                <td>@item.MaterialPacking.DescriptionFr</td>
            } else { 
                <td>@item.MaterialPacking.DescriptionNl</td> 
            }

            <td>@item.Quantity</td>
            ...
```

I think the code clarity is not optimal but I don't think creating a helper specific for this is necessary. Are there any other possibilities?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is an extract of data I retrieve from my repository.

[image]

As you can see I have 2 possibilities: ...fr or ...nl

I need a specific item based on the current culture.

here is the linq:

```
var request = requestRepository.Find(x => x.RequestID == requestID)
                .MyInclude(x => x.TransportedMaterials.Select(y => y.MaterialPacking)).FirstOrDefault();

return request.TransportedMaterials;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom ViewModel, you can make it the controller's responsibility to populate the `MaterialPacking` property with the message in the correct language. That moves the code out of the view.

However, the `if/else` statement is still bad practice. What happens if you decide to support Spanish? Do you want to modify every one of these `if` statements throughout the code? You should create a service where you can pass it the key for a message and it will give you back the actual message in the current language.

So your controller code would end up saying something like this:

```
item.MaterialPackingDescription = 
    _languageService.GetDescription(item.MaterialPacking);
```

And your view code:

```
<td>@item.MaterialPackingDescription</td>
```

Comment: And in fact there is no need to implement anything: The ResourceManager provides all this functionality, based on Thread.CurrentUICulture, with nice things such as language fallback, and Visual Studio makes it easy to manage localizations used by ResourceManager in .resx files.

Comment: @Clafou: Cool. I haven't actually dealt with localization, so I was mostly looking at this from a software design perspective. Even using the ResourceManager, though, I'd probably recommend abstracting that into the language service in order to improve unit-testability of the controller. (I'm a big fan of dependency injection and loose coupling.)

Comment: I know about localisation and resx files but in my case here translations are stored in my DB (user is responsible for adding/editing/removing items in this db). I updated my question to show you the data I retrieved in my repository.

Comment: @Bronzato: All the more reason to use a separate service for this sort of thing. You can encapsulate your current logic for choosing the `MaterialPacking`'s description within that class. You could define an interface that allows you to get multi-lingual descriptions from a variety of different object types so that a single method could handle a variety of circumstances. And if you decide to change how you get these descriptions, you'll only have to change one point in code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need special casing (it wouldn't scale: if you were to add one more language, you'd have to go in an add a new `else` block everywhere you do this). The way to get localized strings is to use the built-in resource manager. Visual Studio makes this very easy... Look it up (or look up localization) in MSDN.

So your code would become:

```
        <td>@item.Title</td>
        <td>@item.SubTitle</td>

        <td>@Resources.MaterialPackingDescription</td>

        <td>@item.Quantity</td>
        ...
```

Note that you are also using the wrong property: For resources you should use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` rather than CurrentCulture.

Answer (score 0):

Why not perform this logic in your controller or view model. Then you wouldn't need to do it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blogpost about Localization](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html).

With resource files you'll be able to keep your view cleaner because there's no need for if constructions to display messages in the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

You must store your string values in App_GlobalResources, and then use it from there.

Check [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx) article for more help